# Generated schema gives warnings during build

Tags: biztalk

I am using schemas generated with WCF-SQL adapter for TypedPolling to get items from database. Multiple items are returned and debatching is performed in the standard XMLReceive pipeline.

I use following configuration to get detaching to work:

- Schema root node: Envelope = Yes
- TypedPolling node: Body XPath = TypedPolling-TypedPollingResultSet0
- TypedPolling-TypedPollingResultSet0 node: Min = 0, Max = 1
- TypedPolling-TypedPollingResultSet0-TypedPollingResultSet0 node: Min = 0, Max = unbounded

Inbound map targets TypedPolling-TypedPollingResultSet0-TypedPollingResultSet0 node.

However, I get following warnings during build:

> warning BEC1008: Node "TypedPollingResultSet0" - Body XPath property is invalid or references a node that may not exist in the schema.
>
> warning BEC1008: Node "ArrayOfTypedPollingResultSet0" - Body XPath property is invalid or references a node that may not exist in the schema.

Resolution of the warnings above is to set schema root node Root Reference property to TypedPolling:

- Schema root node: Root Reference = TypedPolling

However, I get following error message when running:

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Receive Port: "" URI: "" Reason: The document specification by message type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/SchemaName#TypedPollingResultSet0" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.

Is it possible to do this scenario right, or do I have to live with warnings during build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you saw is essentially normal and expected.  It's just a Warning and it technically correct in that TypedPolling and it's ancestors are min=0.  You can safely ignore it.  You will get many simiar warnings from the Mapper as well.

Because the Schema defines multiple messages, you will have to undo Schema root node.

Again, provided everything otherwise works, ignore the Warnings.

Comment: Too bad... :(
Thanks for responding.

Comment: @JERKER Sorry, don't understand.  What's Too bad?  This is a problem at all.  Don't forget to Upvote or Accept Answers.

Comment: A lots of warnings that I have investigated and wanted to get rid of. Possibly hides other warnings of interest. Thats too bad. I will wait and see if there are any other answer to get...if not, I'll accept answer.

Comment: @JERKER There are no other answers, you'll see.  :)  It's well known in the BizTalk community that Warnings aren't even worth displaying in VS.  Seriously, just go to Errors, un-select Warnings and problem solved!

Comment: Too bad... :( :(